# How to find the probability of a continous random variable at a point using its cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have the cumulative distribution function

$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
  0 & x<0\\    
  x & 0 \le x \le 1\\
  1 & x > 1  
\end{cases}$

How am I meant to find, for example, $P(X = 0.25)$, using this function? My first instinct is to use the derivative of the function, but that would only give me its probability *density*, not the actual probability of X taking a certain value. What is the way of going about this? The fact that the variable is continuous is throwing me off. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That probability is zero, because of continuity at that point. The density at $0.25$ tells you what the ratio $\frac{P(|X - 0.25| < \epsilon)}{2\epsilon}$ is close to for small $\epsilon$ i.e. how the probability of it being in and around $0.25$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(X=0.25)=P(X\leq 0.25 )-P(X < 0.25)
=F_X(0.25)-F_X(0.25^{-})=0.25-0.25=0$

For any continues random variable $P(X=a)=0$ since

$P(X=a)=P(X\in \{a \})=\int_{x \in \{a \}} dP=0$
since measure of $\{a \}$ is zero.